# Nothing output in laravel blade please find my error. I don't know what happen

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm a newbaby to laravel and view.I don't know to solve this problem. Please find my bug.
*I commented in app.js*

```
 const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: "haha"
    };
  }
});
```

*instead written in main.blade.php*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="{{ asset('css/app.css')}}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      @{{message}}
      <script>
          const app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data() {
              return {
                message: "haha"
              };
            }
          });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*but when I run with route in web.php*

```
    Route::get('/main',function(){
  return view("layouts.main");
});
```

*nothing display. This is page source code*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://localhost:8000/css/app.css">
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/app.js">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      {{message}}
      <script>
          const app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data() {
              return {
                message: "haha"
              };
            }
          });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*and then the code in webpack.mix.js*

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps()
```

*please light me up in this bug.
I have spent a lot of time. I still lose solution.*

Answer (score 0):

You must put your script tag outside of the #app div

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://localhost:8000/css/app.css">
        <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/app.js">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app">
          {{message}}
          
        </div>
<script> 
const app = new Vue({
                el: "#app",
                data() {
                  return {
                    message: "haha"
                  };
                }
              });
          </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```